# C++ and output on files

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, for-loop

I was trying to do a C++ program who do a thing like this:
in a list of surname and name (file), read the same surname and stamp in another file 'people with surname *surname* are: *name*,*name*,*name* etc..
That's is what i did, but something went wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct persona
{
    string nome;
    string cognome;
};

int carica_vettore (persona a [])
{
    string name, surname;
    int i=0, np=0;
    ifstream fin ("people.txt");
    while (cin >> name >> surname) 
    {
        if (name == "0" && surname == "0")
            break;

        a[i].nome = name;
        a[i].cognome = surname;
        i++;
        np++;
    }
    return np;

}

int main ()
{
    string nomepers, cognomepers;
    int cont = 0;
    persona persone [50];
    cont = carica_vettore(persone);
    for (int k = 0; k < cont; k++)
    {
        for (int j = k+1; j < cont-1; j++)
            if (persone[k] == persone[j])
                cout << "People with surname (" << persone[i] << "), are: " << persone[i].nome;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

And also i forget to stamp on file, but i think that's is not such a big problem

So, anyone could help me?

2 'for' who check if there is any same surnames btw

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your program? what output do you get? does it crash? Please update your question with more information.

Comment: @KLibby don't stamp, it crash yes, i can't get output. Also have this error:
39 17 [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'persona' and 'persona')

Comment: How can it crash and not compile at the same time?

Comment: @LogicStuff if i try to delete that, this will crash

Comment: You can't just fix compile errors by deleting the problem lines! you need to *fix* them! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you mean to read from a file?

```
ifstream fin("people.txt");
while(cin >> name >> surname) // cin reads from the console, waits for your input
```

Replace `cin` with `fin`.

You also don't have `operator==` for `persona` overloaded:

```
bool operator==(persona const& other) const
{
    return nome == other.nome && cognome == other.cognome;
}
```

And also `operator<<`, which is required here:

```
cout << "People with surname (" << persone[i] << ...
```

Print `persone[i].nome` or `persone[i].cognome` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's right, i forgot to add cognome at persone[i]

Answer (score 1):

`if (persone[k] == persone[j])` is the problem. The error message tells you what is wrong and what the line number is. you are comparing two Persona structs, but you cannot use the `==` operator on them. maybe you should compare their nome or cognome values instead.

Comment: nome e cognome should be in the struct vector, and, if i remember, i already use the ==

Comment: They are, but you cannot use `==` on the struct directly, which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, yeah i understood i think. I have to compare cognome[k] and cognome[j]?

Comment: @KLibby, Of course he can use `operator==()` on struct since he is using C++, and C++ compilation provides implicit operators.

Comment: @ValentinTrinque - in that case could you explain the compile error that the OP posted in their question comments? I am curious.

Comment: Well my bad ! This operator cannot be implicit actually. This one has to be implemented since compiler doesn't know about the comparison policy ( reference or deep comparison mechanics). I have been rushy but the statement "They are, but you cannot use == on the struct directly, which is what you are trying to do." led me to the wrong interpretation of your thoughts: "you cannot use operator== with struct" which is wrong.